# How to display HTML tags as plain text in extjs displayfield

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I am using a displayField in ext js and setting the content to be displayed using "Value" property.
When the value has HTML tags e.g: `<b> sample </b>`, EXT JS is rendering the word "sample" in bold. 
Can any one please help me to display the text as it is, i.e. `<b> sample </b>` instead of the word sample in Bold letters.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Vasavi.

Comment: @Ruddy - Thanks for the Edit suggestion, can you please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Ext.String.htmlEncode(value)` before setting the value. This method converts special characters to their HTML character equivalents.